# Link one directory to network drive

Tags: windows, networking, spotify

Spotify removed the option of where to put the offline files. I had them on my NAS where I have lot of space. I run spotify on a computer with a small hard disk on c:.

Can I somehow redirect the directory c:\users\Foo\AppData\Local\Spotify to read and write to z:\spotify?

Comment: What's the NAS run, and what is its filesystem?

Comment: Windows. I can also put it on another drive locally if that is possible, just not C:

Comment: Ahh, symlinks *might* work here, but I'm not totally sure

Comment: Tanks. That might work to redirect to another local drive. Not the network-drive or nas though.

Comment: @ekenman Symbolic links can span volumes and can use UNC paths. See http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html. You can refer to a network drive using a UNC path. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141941

Answer (score 0):

You can use soft links to achieve this as Windows has supported them in NTFS for a long time.

You can create them from the command line but personally I prefer to use LinkShellExtension which gives you the ability to create all the kinds of links Windows understands right from Windows Explorer.

The main problem you are likely to get though is if/when the NAS network drive is not connected. I've seen Windows get confused with this situation too often to rely on it without some careful testing. Should be fine if the computer is a desktop that is always connected however.

Comment: I can't get it to work with soft links